# Is the expression "done right" proper grammar?

Tags: grammar, idioms

Suppose I have the sentence: "This is a website done right."

It sounds wrong, but I cannot find any grammatical rules that confirm my suspicions. Am I just crazy or is that improper grammar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [M-W.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right), *right (adverb)* can mean "in a suitable, proper, or desired manner", and gives as an example of that usage "knew he wasn't doing it right."  So I'm gonna have to go with the "you're just crazy" option.  :-)

Comment: How dare you call me crazy! Actually that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It may sound wrong because it's a contraction - the full form is "this is a website that was done right". Now that's ugly passive voice, I think "someone did a great job on this website" sounds better.

In other words, it's wrong in the same way as "as seen on TV" is wrong :-)

Comment: +1 for passive voice. I think there's a decent chance that is why it sounds wrong to me :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/right) for "right", there is no meaning of "right" that is an adverb meaning "correctly" (however, there are other adverbial meanings of "right"). So, if you trust it as a source, the (pedantic, technical, grammatical) answer is no. *However, "done right" is very commonly used in **informal** contexts in American English to mean "done correctly".* I would not say or write "done right" in any formal context.

Comment: But it is in the entry for adverb *right* in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right?show=2&t=1297383062).

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Merriam-Webster ≫ Wiktionary :-P  Although, I’d agree with @Nick that regardless of whether it’s grammatically correct, “done right” is associated more with informal than with formal usage.